# How to use EmbedCode with CloudDeploy correctly?

Tags: wolfram-cloud, web-access, html, cloud-deploy, api

I ran `EmbedCode[CloudDeploy[Manipulate[Plot[Sin[x + c], {x, -6, 6}], {c, -1, 1}]]]` based on [this instruction](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/CreateInteractiveContentForTheWeb.html) and obtained the html code for embedding as below:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<iframe src="https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/15ac46d4-e6db-43fd-b888-8bfe57b19e9a?_embed=iframe" width="600" height="800"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

And then I pasted the above html code in the [Tryit Editor of w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_embed), but the `Manipulate` doesn't show.

And then I tried to paste the code to Wordpress and Google Sites, but also don't work for these two sites.

Is there a way to run this in either Wordpress or Google site? Are there any requirements I (or the website) need to fulfill so that the `Manipulate` can run?

Many thanks!

Comment: Do you mean that 403 appears? If so then add Permissions -> "Public" to CloudDeploy. It works for me.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. With `Permissions -> "Public"`, for me, it still don't work on Wordpress and Google site...

Comment: Elaborate on "still does not work".

Comment: In wordpress, after pasting the code, the manipulate appears in the draft after pasting the code, but all respective html code would disappear whenever the post is published. In google site, whenever I paste the code, I got `Code:30e552b` and `Error:Client Error`. I tried to Google `30e552b` to understand what it is but have no result.